# Angular2 how to use location.back() and stop at the URL with the app has started?

Tags: angular

In my ng2 app I have a back button with this.location.back(). It basically works well like the back button of the Web browser. However, I would like the back button will not do the back function when getting back to the point where the ng2 app has started, and the back button will be gray out, just as the back button of the Web browser will?

Answer (score 4):

In the Angular RC4 router you can access the current router state by calling `router.url`

```
constructor(private router:Router) { console.log(this.router.url); }
```

Simply add your check to the `[disabled]` attribute binding.

```
<button [disabled]="this.router.url === '/somePath'">Back</button>
```

edit:

If you would like to disable the button before the application was navigated to, grab the current window history by calling:

`initLength = window.history.length`
 When your application is initialized.

Now create a function in some service that the back button can call every time the user wishes to navigate back, and disable it when the current `window.history.length == initLength`.

```
    someBackMethod() {
     if(window.history.length == initLength) {
      someBool = false;
     }
     else { 
      window.history.back(); 
      }
    }
```

Finally set the [disabled] attribute binding.

```
<button [disabled]="someBool">Back</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However, I would expect something similar to the browser history of the tab, because the startup path may had been through a few times, as the user might actually press the app's home button to get back the the app's startup path. The solutions in this answer may make the back button stop too early, when the path matches.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect what you needed. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I spent 8 hours on this and this is definitely best solution. Initial history length is really clever approach.